# I am trying to filter records based on date field format "YYYYMMDD" through awk command . Source & Target file is comma separated with Header

Tags: date, awk, filter

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","};(NR>=2){($2 > "20210331");}' test1.csv > test.csv
```

File test1.csv:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,20210101,JohnA
B,20210101,JohnB
G,20210501,JohnG
C,20210108,JohnC
D,20210202,JohnD
E,20210331,JohnE
F,20210401,JohnF
H,20210715,JohnH
```

Expected output:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
G,20210501,JohnG
F,20210401,JohnF
H,20210715,JohnH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply treat the dates in your shown samples like integers and compare them. In order to print the header, you need a separate condition.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{print;next} 20210331<$2' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder.. How can u sort the records based on date if the date is in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: @vineetmadan, Hello Vineet, In my humble opinion, you could open a new question for this one, as one thread one question is what we encourage users here(else future readers may get confuse). Also make sure you do add your tried code in your next thread(else your question may close, just a friendly advice here), cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the shorter code below:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = OFS = ","}(FNR == 1) || ($2 > 20210331)' test1.csv
```

Comment: You're not using OFS so no need to set it. It doesn't do any harm of course.